# Datanucleus + GWT Compilation process

Tags: gwt, jdo, datanucleus

I trying to compile with a GWT+App Engine+JDO+Datanucleus project with Maven. 
When maven start to compile the java sources I get the error:

```
    [DEBUG] Source roots:
[DEBUG]  /home/desarrollo26/eclipse-workspace/projectName/src
[DEBUG]  /home/desarrollo26/eclipse-workspace/projectName/target/generated-sources/annotations
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d /home/desarrollo26/eclipse-workspace/projectName/target/projectName-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes -classpath (all .m2 dependencies)
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#beforeRebuildExecution
[INFO] Compiling 644 source files to /home/desarrollo26/eclipse-workspace/projectName/target/projectName-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes
DataNucleus : JDOQLTypedQuery Q class generation : com.projectName.server.extension.TokenExtension -> com.projectName.server.extension.QTokenExtension
```

I followed all the datanucleus-maven, JDO and Enhanced process from the Datanucleus documentation page and JDO and JDO Query are present in the CLASSPATH but the persistent error is:

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.814 s (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-17T13:00:24+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project Nubbius: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jdo/query/PersistableExpression: javax.jdo.query.PersistableExpression
```

Actually, my dependencies for JDO/JPA, Datanucleus:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.16</version>
   <optional>true</optional>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-jdo-query -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-jdo-query</artifactId>
        <version>(3.9, )</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3</version>
  </dependency>
```

The plugin for Datanucleus auto-enhancer:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0-m1</version>
            <configuration>
                <api>JDO</api>
                <props>${basedir}/datanucleus.properties</props>
                <log4jConfiguration>${project.basedir}/src/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                <enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>false</fork>
                <metadataIncludes>**/*.jdo</metadataIncludes>
                <metadataIncludes>**/*.class</metadataIncludes>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency> 
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3</version>
              </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-enhancer -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </dependency>
                </dependencies> 
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <phase>process-classes</phase> 
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
  <plugin>
```

And here the GWT build process:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-rc-8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <moduleName>com.projectName.Administracion</moduleName>
      <moduleName>com.projectName.Cronometro</moduleName>
      <moduleName>com.projectName.Extension</moduleName>
      <moduleName>com.projectName.projectName</moduleName>
      <failOnError>true</failOnError>
      <!-- GWT compiler 2.8 requires 1.8, hence define sourceLevel here if you use
           a different source language for java compilation -->
      <sourceLevel>1.8</sourceLevel>
      <!-- Compiler configuration -->
      <compilerArgs>
        <!-- https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html -->
        <!-- Ask GWT to create the Story of Your Compile (SOYC) (gwt:compile) -->
        <arg>-compileReport</arg>
        <arg>-XcompilerMetrics</arg>
        <arg>-Xms1024M</arg>
        <arg>-Xmx2014M</arg>
      </compilerArgs>
      <style>DETAILED</style>
      <draftCompile>TRUE</draftCompile>
      <localWorkers>6</localWorkers>
      <!-- CodeserverMode configuration (for debugging in SuperDevMode -->
      <!-- https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/codeserver-mojo.html --> 
      <codeServerPort>9997</codeServerPort>

      <jvmArgs>
        <arg>-Xms1024M</arg>
        <arg>-Xmx2014M</arg>
        <arg>-javaagent:localDependenciesPath/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.59/lib/agent/appengine-agent.jar </arg>
      </jvmArgs>
      <classpathScope>runtime</classpathScope>
      <!-- URL(s) that should be opened by DevMode (gwt:devmode). -->
      <startupUrls>
        <startupUrl>projectName.jsp</startupUrl>
      </startupUrls>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

    <!-- Compilador --> 
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Does any one know what can cause that error? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you putting "datanucleus-jdo-query" in the CLASSPATH? Need typed queries? Since you dont post what else is in the CLASSPATH its pointless guessing; a `pom.xml` would reveal such things

Comment: If you are going to put "datanucleus-jdo-query" in the classpath (and why would you use the latest version, when you use all other DataNucleus jars as ancient versions?), so where is "javax.jdo jdo-api" ? That is required and that is why you get an error message. But then you haven't answered why you are putting "datanucleus-jdo-query" in the classpath to start with. Also why have JDO AND JPA?

Comment: @BillyFrost Thanks for your answer. I have edited my question! When the datanucleus-jdo-query dependenci is out, I get the "package org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.memory does not exist" notification.

Comment: @BillyFrost The "javax.jdo jdo-api" it's in the classpath (sorry, I forgot to inlcuded it in the answer code). I'm following the [JDO Tools Guide](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/tools.html#maven).

Comment: Why would you follow a document from DataNucleus when you are using AppEngine? AppEngine uses ANCIENT versions of jars, and things like "datanucleus-jdo-query" are not part of that. And that guide does not tell you to use BOTH JDO and JPA. You choose the API that you need, and nothing else. Omitting "datanucleus-jdo-query" has nothing *at all* to do with "org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.memory".